# How can I actually edit a HTML element with JavaScript, just like you do in the dev console by clicking "Edit as HTML"

Tags: javascript, html

Disclaimer: I am a massive beginner

So I was having fun with JavaScript and I wondered if instead of using innerHTML if you wanted to change the text or style.color for css fun or whatever (I am a beginner to all of this) you can actually rewrite the element, like if I wanted to target the title of this question as an example, should look probably something like this in the html:

`<a href="/questions/78202361/how-can-i-actually-edit-a-html-element-with-javascript-just-like-you-do-in-the" class="question-hyperlink">How can I actually edit a HTML element with JavaScript, just like you do in the dev console by clicking "Edit as HTML"</a>`

and lets say with JavaScript I want to edit the color, so adding [...]`just <span style="color:red">like</span> you do in` [...]  (I used [...] to skip some text cause of my long question)

Basically my question is if I can retype a element completely within a script, or maybe you have to cut it, change it, and then create a new one.

I didn't find the answer nowhere else or maybe I'm just using the wrong terms

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents should give you everything you need. In summary for this specific cases: find a way to select that particular element (this is likely the trickiest part, since this is not a webpage you control), then if you assign that to a variable called `element`, just do `element.style.color = "red";`

Comment: of course you can as long as you know how to reference the element you want to change. For example `let titleElement = document.querySelector("#question-header");` and now you can play with the element

Comment: When you operate on elements in JavaScript, you generally deal with them as DOM objects, you don't edit them as text.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should learn from tutorials on web programming. SO is not a tutoring service, we can't teach these basics here.